# Help with simplification of this expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, products

So i have derived this expression and would like to simplify it (i.e find an expression purely in terms of J and v).

$$ J\bigg[1+\sum_{n=1}^{J-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k(1-v)(J-k)}{(k+1)(J-k-1 + vk)}\bigg]$$

So far we can get

$$ J\bigg[1+\sum_{n=1}^{J-1}\frac{(1-v)^n}{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(J-k)}{(J-k-1 + vk)}\bigg]$$
I know that $0 \leq v \leq 1$ and that $J$ is an integer $\geq 1$

I've tried shoving it into Mathematica and have not managed to obtain a simpler form for the full expression. Any suggestions or is this the best i can get?

Comment: Is $J$ integer or just real ?

Comment: You should begin by factorizing $(1-v)^n$ out of the $\Sigma$ symbol...

Comment: You can split off the product of $k/(k+1)$ and it cancels down to $1/(n+1)$

Comment: J is an Integer. I saw that we could factorize (1-v) but that didn't help me get much further unfortunately.